# How to fix SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function in Google cloud vision

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'd like to use Google cloud vision API. I copied the code but I'm getting the following error : SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
 */
const fileName = '/Tickets/leclerc.jpg';

// Performs text detection on the local file
const [result] = await client.textDetection(fileName);
const detections = result.textAnnotations;
console.log('Text:');
detections.forEach(text => console.log(text));
```

Any ideas on how to solve it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Put the code in an `async` function? I mean, the error is pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An await method needs to be enclosed into an async function, this is pretty easy to fix.

```
const detectLocalFile = async function() {
  const [result] = await client.textDetection(fileName);
  {...}
}
```